# VS010, VS 2012 - Oracle Exception (EZ CONNECT)

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2010, exception, visual-studio-2012

I installed the last Oracle client and tried with both VS (2010,2012) to connect to an Oracle database using the EZ Connect. I set :

> User name = SYSDBA,  Password = MY_PWD,  Connection type = EZ Connect,
>   DB host name : MY_SERVER,  Port : 1521,  Data source name : ORCL,

When I test the connection I get the following error : The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution' threw an exception.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Start Oracle client's "Oracle Net Manager" and enable `EZCONNECT` method:

1. Select "Local" -> "Profile"
2. In "Available methods" select `EZCONNECT` and press `>` button
3. Close window and press "Save"

Maybe this helps.

Comment: Hi Rimas, thanks for your answer. I did activate the EZ Connect in the configuration files. Before it wasn't available in the GUI. I notice I have 2 Oracle client installed, only one appears in the 'Remove program'. Maybe an installation failed. I asked for a brute reset of the hard drive.I hope the problem will not appear again.